# Accessing the currently executing "request" or "thread" as if it were global in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, global-variables, process

In Rails the current thread is used a lot to store global variables (I know, global variables are evil, but they are sometimes necessary).

```
Thread.current[:authlogic_scope] = scope
```

Here are some of the places it is used:

- [active_record/scoping.rb#L18](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/15bfaa3d13f84c689f9182c0be658ddde019e572/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping.rb#L18)
- [authlogic/session/activation.rb#L29](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/40c0e16d13329a9a1dc81a1598e5eaa38a7acc39/lib/authlogic/session/activation.rb#L29)

The question is, can you do a similar thing in Node.js? Specifically, in an express app.

**What is the best way to keep a reference to the current request (or current thread)?**

In express you're using callbacks with the request/response objects to avoid having to set global variables, which makes sense:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send('Hello World');
});
```

This question is in regards to building an "identity map" for caching database records (scoped to the current HTTP request / current user). In Rails, they can do this by keeping the identity map scoped to `Thread.current`, and because everything is synchronous. Is there a way to do this in Node.js?

One way is to pass the `request` around to every function. For my particular case this is too complicated to do and I would like to avoid this if at all possible.

Another way to do this is to redefine all of the variables you're going to use in a custom javascript function, similar to the way you do view templating (define variables that feel like global variables from with a template). But for my particular case this would be more confusing than helpful.

The third way to is to set it to some global variable that is accessible only to the current HTTP request, or the current thread. Is this possible in Node.js? If not, what are some other ways to accomplish the same thing?

Basically, I want to be able to do

```
App.User.where({createdAt: {'>=': _(2).days().ago()}}).all()
```

and have it internally check some node.js `process.CURRENT_REQUEST` that's scoped to the current request, where the `App.User` query can store it's results (and any other models can store their results, so if they are requested again it doesn't hit the database). I also want to be able to pass around the `currentUser` the same way Authlogic does, so whenever a record is created, for instance, the `createdById` field will be set to `process.CURRENT_REQUEST.currentUser` automatically (internally).

Answer (score 2):

You don't mean thread.  JavaScript is single-threaded, so node is single-threaded.
I don't mean to be picky, but people will understand you better if you use the nomenclature they've learned.  The words 'thread' and 'process' are already too heavility overloaded at the OS level, best to avoid them unless that's really what we mean.

It is quite common in node to pass the entire request object around.

You have not provided a strong use case for building this identity map.  Can you elaborate?

If you really need to keep track of individual callbacks, you could use a guid-generator.  Of course, you have to store those guids someplace and depending on how you do that you could end up creating a bottleneck for scaling.

Ah.. I see your edit now... Where you write "where the App.User query can store it's results (and any other models can store their results, so if they are requested again it doesn't hit the database)." you're already thinking at a very high level.  This is less of a node.js question and more of a framework question.  What I mean is, node.js is a low-level kit which markets itself as a high-level framework.  It's basically a mashup of javascript with an event loop supported by a thread pool.  That would be OS threads, by the way.  I think the answer to your question may be that you need to explicitly provide caching in your objects if you're looking to avoid extra hits to the database.  As far as I know, there's no high-level magic for that baked into node.  I know that doesn't really help, except maybe to say don't feel bad about not finding something that isn't there.

Re: globals. Just don't do it.  Friends don't let their friends write to global.  :)

Comment: What do you recommend I call it? I get what you're saying, but for my particular case passing the request all over the place would be undesirable (appended to question). Is there no way to keep track of processes/threads/whatever-theyre-called in Node.js to avoid passing the request around?

Comment: It would be nice to know in general how executing code in Node.js is executed, how it jumps between callbacks and such and if it stores some sort of process id or something.

Comment: I agree that avoiding globals is a good thing. However, globals are, I'd say, one of the major things that made Rails possible (clean api), if you really look at the source code. They are the foundation for making database queries, for example.

Comment: Good meta-question.  You're either talking about an HTTP request, a request handler for an HTTP method (eg. GET, POST, ...) or a callback function passed to a request handler -- which may be an anonymous function as in your original example.

Comment: There is really good discussion on the node.js mailing list of how the node.js event loop works.  As you start to grok it, much of the magic and hype will be replaced by "oh, yeah, that's cool, I get it."  I don't have a lot of advice except to read old posts on the node.js list.

Comment: Sure, without globals I could not boot my computer or write the first compiler or write a device-level kernel driver.  After that, the justifications for globals start to dwindle but not to zero I agree.  The question is, do I want to inflict that pain on myself?  A better question is, do I want to inflict that pain on someone else ?